# Adjust background size for an advertising skin

Tags: css

I'm trying to fix an issue. I have a background advertising (skin) and I must increase the size: the same adv is served for two website, but one of the website has a larger container.

I try with background-size property, but when I try to set "110%" the behavior of the background is related to the windows, so if I resize the browser the skin follow the browser.

Ho can I increase the size of the background keeping it centered on the container?

Comment: use `background-position: center center` to keep the background centered as well.

Comment: doesn't work...

My background properties are 

background: url(http://ixxxx) 50% 0% no-repeat fixed;

Comment: could you please provide your code here, as It's hard to see what the issue is. However, this *should* work.

Comment: @jbutler483 I will try to recreate the situation. The main problem is that using background-size property the image scale as you scale the browser windows, I have to avoid the scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Using `background-size:cover` you can make a (centered) image stretch over the full size of a container element. For example:

```
.background {
   background: url(image.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Try scaling the result field in [this example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2m4p54k/). You'll see the image scaling to fill the div no matter what format. Read more about using `background-size: cover` it [on CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).